# Invisible Google reCaptcha

Tags: html, button, input, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I know this type of question has been asked before, but I couldn't get the answer. I have a contact form, and I want to implement the new Invisible Google Recaptcha. However, I have used an `<input>` rather than a `<button>` and I can't figure out how to do this. Here is my code for the contact form I have:

```css
input, textarea {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, serif;
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: none;
}

input[type=text], textarea {
    width: 350px;
    background-color: #b6b6b4;
    border: 1px solid #989898;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
input[type=submit] {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #989898;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    font-size: large;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #848484;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=submit]:active {
    background-color: #989898;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<!--CONTACT FORM-->



<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
 
        <div>
            <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name..." required> <br> </div>
            <div>
            <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email..." required>
            <br>
            </div>

  <input type="checkbox" name="maillist" value="1" checked> Subscribe to mailing list<br>



            <div>
            <input name="game" type="text" placeholder="Game suggestions...">
            <br>
            </div>


            <div>
            <textarea cols="30" name="comment" rows="9" placeholder="Comments..."></textarea>
            <br> </div>
            

        <div>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"> </div>
    </form>
```

Then I have the google ReCaptcha button:

```html
<button
class="g-recaptcha"
data-sitekey="############################"
data-callback="YourOnSubmitFn">
Submit
</button>
```

Any Help would be appreciated. Also, I was wondering if you could remove the ReCaptcha logo on the bottom right.

[image: This Picture Shows What I mean]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible) docs check this g-recaptcha tag attributes and grecaptcha.render parameters section:

- **g-recaptcha tag attribute**: data-badge
- **grecaptcha.render parameter**: badge
- **Value**: bottomright
         bottomleft
         inline
- **Default**: bottomright
- **Description**: Optional. Reposition the reCAPTCHA badge. 'inline' allows you to control the CSS.

This is a basic [example](https://recaptcha.affe.network/invisible)

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>reCaptcha example</title>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <style>
        .grecaptcha-badge {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="demo-form" action="/post" method="post">
        <button data-sitekey="your_site_key" data-callback='onSubmit' data-badge="inline">Login</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Set the `data-badge` attribute to `inline`, notice the `data-badge="inline"`:

```
<button type="submit" data-sitekey="your_site_key" data-callback='onSubmit' data-badge="inline">Login</button>
```

And on the html code:

```
<style>
    .grecaptcha-badge {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

You could also just add to your CSS:

```
.grecaptcha-badge {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try this, It will hide the Google reCaptcha Invisible Badge over the page.

`.grecaptcha-badge {
    display: none !important;
}`

Keep in mind the badge should be displayed as Google pretends the "privacy" and "terms" links to be present.

Comment: It sounds really good, but I'm not very good at this so do I just place this code in my css? Do I use the normal recaptcha and add this or the invisible one? Thank you so much for your help